# For each before selected div in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to perform an action on each element above the one with an id of `id3`

**HTML**

```
<div id="id4"></div>
<div id="id5"></div>
<div id="id1"></div>
<div id="id3"></div>
<div id="id6"></div>
```

I'm selecting `id3`  and I want to do some manipulation of `id1`, `id5` and `id4`. But not `id6`.

How can I do it?

Comment: Its still not clear what you are trying to do, can you please elaborate?

Comment: `$("#id3").prevAll()` is what you are looking for?

Comment: Presuming that by accepting my answer this is what you want. I've altered your question to reflect this. It's a good idea to do this when a question is poorly recieved. If not you could end up with a question ban

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presuming you want to do some action on every div prior to the selected one you want something along the lines of:

```
$('#id3').prevAll().each(function() {
    var item = $(this);
    //item will be id1, id5 and id4 respoectively.
});
```

Bear in mind that if you simply want to do something to all these items then you probably don't want the `each()`. So for example:

```
$('#id3').prevAll().css( "background-color", "red" );
```

It's also a good iea to make your code more resilient and check for it not returning anything:

```
var allPrevious = $('#id3').prevAll();
if (allPrevious){
   allPrevious.each(function() {
        var item = $(this);
        //item will be id1, id5 and id4 respoectively.
    });
}
```

Thurns them all read. Basically the [JQuery docs on `prevAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/prevall/) cover this with examples, etc.

> Given a jQuery object that represents a set of DOM elements, the
>   .prevAll() method searches through the predecessors of these elements
>   in the DOM tree and construct a new jQuery object from the matching
>   elements; the elements are returned in order beginning with the
>   closest sibling.